# On duplicate key update … time stamp not updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have an query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml 
                (title, album, artist) 
        VALUES ('$pieces[2]', '$pieces[1]', '$pieces[0]') 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            time = now(), 
            album = VALUES(album), 
            artist = VALUES(artist)";
```

the table is:
[image]

it updates, but keeps adding, creating new lines, it does not update:
[image]

Comment: Since you don't have a `UNIQUE` key (just a `PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT`) then `ON DUPLICATE KEY` never triggers.

Comment: If `title` is supposed to be unique, then add a `UNIQUE` key to that column, but bear in mind that song titles are not unique in real life.

Comment: Also, obligatory MySQL INJECTION WARNING.

Comment: And one more thing: you can set `TIMESTAMP` columns to have `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, removing the need for you to update it manually.

Comment: Yes, before taking another step, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries - no ifs, no buts!

Comment: Yes that was the problem. @Niet the Dark Absol that is the answer, you can put it at the answer.

Comment: the id increases several times, as the number the times it tries to update. istead 1..2..3 it goes 1..4..16, does anybody now why? @NiettheDarkAbsol

Comment: I think that depends on the database engine - I don't recall seeing that behaviour with InnoDB but maybe I just never noticed. It shouldn't matter though, unless you've got billions of rows - and even then just make it a BIGINT.